# Вывод символов кириллицы через терминал

Tags: консоль, кодировка, visual-studio-code, utf-8, scanner

обращаюсь второй раз с этой проблемой, но стараюсь описать ее детальнее. Пожалуйста, перед тем, как кидать ссылки на похожие вопросы, вчитайтесь в мою проблему, мне ранее кидали ссылки на действия, которые я уже предпринимал. С популярными решениями проблемы ознакомлен, они сводятся к тому, что я уже предпринял.

Так вот, проблема состоит в том, что терминал powershell выводит ранее введенные данные русскими символами в виде пустых символов. Для наглядности я написал простейший код, который позволяет увидеть в терминале введенное значение строки

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");

        System.out.println("Введите строку:");
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Вы ввели: " + line);

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

В IDE (VS code) я сохранил файл с кодировкой UTF-8 и в json файле настроек прописал автоматическое переключение кодировки терминала на UTF-8 (65001). Знаю, в java разработке Vs Code не любят, но проблема на нем не ограничивается. При запуске кода через терминал windows или powershell введенные русские символы все равно не отображаются.

Касаемо терминала(powershell), в нем я пробовал менять шрифт на тот, который поддерживает отображение русских символов и запускал виртуалку java с параметром -encoding UTF-8

Также я поменял локаль на en-US, даже сменил отображение даты и времени на английские. В настройках яызка выбрана поддержка UTF-8

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тут стоило бы начать с понимания того, в какой кодировке вы выводите и получаете текст. Указание UTF-8 для сканера ни разу не подразумевает, что ввод в него придет в этой кодировке.

Comment: @user7860670, разве использование UTF-8 в настройках языка не гарантирует ввод символов в этой кодировки?